# Google Api - Seperate Object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, cordova, google-analytics, google-api

i'm developing an Application which offers some features around real time statistics from Google Analytics. Therefore, the user has to choose, from which Website (ID) he wants to get these stats.

What i get back if i log in is:

```
{
    "kind": "analytics#accounts",
    "username": "************@gmail.com",
    "totalResults": 2,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "itemsPerPage": 1000,
    "items": [{
        "id": "504*******",
        "kind": "analytics#account",
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/504********",
        "name": "He*****************",
        "permissions": {
            "effective": ["COLLABORATE", "EDIT", "MANAGE_USERS", "READ_AND_ANALYZE"]
        },
        "created": "2014-04-29T11:02:30.458Z",
        "updated": "2014-10-09T17:51:00.985Z",
        "childLink": {
            "type": "analytics#webproperties",
            "href": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/50********/webproperties"
        }
    }, {
        "id": "556******",
        "kind": "analytics#account",
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/556*******",
        "name": "Cor**********",
        "permissions": {
            "effective": ["COLLABORATE", "EDIT", "MANAGE_USERS", "READ_AND_ANALYZE"]
        },
        "created": "2014-10-13T13:22:02.787Z",
        "updated": "2014-10-13T13:22:02.787Z",
        "childLink": {
            "type": "analytics#webproperties",
            "href": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/556******/webproperties"
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

So now i want to create a console.log with just the names from the found IDs. Therefore i tried it with javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.items[0].name.length; i++) { ;
                            console.log(data.items[0].name.length);
```

But every time i call my function i get back: `18`

So i just have 2 propertys in my google analytics account - why do i get back 18 and how can i only get back the names from the 2 propertys?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping through the `name` property of the first account, and presumably that name property has 18 characters in it.

Instead you should do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
  console.log(data.items[i].name);
}
```

That will log the names of every account.